# Missing maven integration for eclipse(Extras)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, maven, helios

I want to install maven plugin on eclipse helios but I can only find the core plugin in market place and extras plugin (maven integration for eclipse(Extras)) is missing. can some one please help in this installation and update me that why Extras have been removed from marketplace.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you may want to use [Eclipse Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/) (3.7), which comes with [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) (successor to [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/)).

If not, you can install `m2eclipse-extras` the traditional way, "Install new software..." using the [archived](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/archived-releases.html) releases.